# NPM can't create nested directories after downloading packages

Tags: node.js, windows, npm, windows-10

I've installed `Nodejs` and also `NPM` on my fresh `Windows 10` and `Windows 8` and tried to download `socket.io` library using this command inside a test directory

> c: \ users \ myname \ desktop \ test

```
npm install socket.io
```

everything goes well while downloading, but after download, all directories are listed inside `node_modules`. like below image.

[image]

as you see all directories are in root of `node_modules` whereas they should be inside `socket.io` directory.

any idea how can I fix this?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is something in the new version on NPM.

In old version, if two modules use same dependency, it will installed it twice. Now, all dependencies installed by defaut in the root of node-modules. IF there is any conflict (two modules need same module but differenct version), it will install it inside the module

You can read more info here:
https://github.com/npm/npm/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

It's similar to what `npm dedupe` do:
https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/dedupe

Comment: This is, why so important to use now  "npm i -s", (save the module in package.json). If you omit it, it will make lot of troubles, and updating upgrading, or any things else...